# Get one month's records form one table by selecting two different dates

Tags: php, mysql

```
if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' ) {
    if( isset( $_POST['date_submit'] ) ) {
        if(isset($_POST['datepicker_from']) && isset($_POST['datepicker_to']))
        {<br/>
            $date_from=$_POST['datepicker_from'];
            $date_to=$_POST['datepicker_to'];
            echo $date_to;
            echo $date_from;
            #$where_query="WHERE order_date >= ".$date_from." AND order_date <= ".$date_to;
        }
        $query="SELECT * FROM invoice WHERE order_date >= ".$date_from." AND order_date <= ".$date_to;
        $result_for_search=mysql_query($query, $con);
        #echo $result_for_search;
        if( $result_for_search ) { echo 'search query for datepicker excuted successfully'; }

        while($row=mysql_fetch_array( $result_for_search ) ) {
            echo $row['id'] . ' ' . $row['customer'] . ' ' . $row['products'] . ' ' . <br/>$row['qty'] .
             ' ' . $row['unit_price'] . ' ' . $row['total_cash'] . ' ' . <br/>$row['payment_type'] . 
             ' ' . $row['order_date'] . ' ' . $row['discount'];
        }
    }
}
```

I am selecting two dates by using javascript `datepicker()` method, when two dates are selected, i want records against that two selected dates. the dates are order_date attribute of my invoice table.

I used `BETWEEN` too. But it did not worked.

Comment: Please tag your questions appropriately - jQuery has nothing to do with anything asked here.

Comment: yes i am just explaining that how i pick date

Comment: What do you mean not worked? Do you get some error, or just empty result?

Comment: query executed successfully but i did't bring any records

Comment: i think i have issue in my select query

Comment: Your dates need to be quoted. But before you go fixing that, you should really consider switching to [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), and using bound parameters.

Comment: check your select query, i think you don  not close it properly, check also for semi-colons and colons in your query..

Comment: I used `BETWEEN` with AND operator but it also did't show records

Comment: `$query="SELECT * FROM invoice WHERE order_date >= '$date_from' AND order_date <= '$date_to'";`
 it did't worked...

Comment: what is the datatype of your table field 'order_date'?

Comment: order_date field type is date

Comment: `"SELECT * FROM invoice WHERE order_date BETWEEN '$date_from' AND '$date_to'"`
used this query too but did't worked...

Comment: Maybe there are no records in your table between those 2 dates.

Comment: i have 4 records in the table and i am selecting that records only to show the data. but it is not working

Comment: Print out the values of `$date_from` and `$date_to` to make sure that they're what you expect them to be (and provide the result here).

Comment: @PatrickQ, yes it printed the dates that i selected from form.

Comment: As I said, _provide the result here_. The dates might not be in MySQL date format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumes that your input are coming in the format mm/dd/yyyy.

You need to convert into mysql format with `date()` and `strtotime`.

```
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' ) {

           $datepicker = '';

    if( isset( $_POST['date_submit'] ) ) {

        if(isset($_POST['datepicker_from']) && isset($_POST['datepicker_to']))
        {
            $date_from = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_POST['datepicker_from']));
            $date_to   = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_POST['datepicker_to']));

        $datepicker = "WHERE order_date >= '$date_from' AND order_date <= '$date_to'";  

    }

            $query="SELECT * FROM invoice $datepicker";
            $result_for_search=mysql_query($query, $con);

        if( $result_for_search ) {

            while($row=mysql_fetch_array( $result_for_search ) ) {

            echo    $row['id'] . ' ' . $row['customer'] . ' ' . $row['products'] . '<br/> ' . 
                    $row['qty'] .' ' . $row['unit_price'] . ' ' . $row['total_cash'] . '<br/> ' . 
                    $row['payment_type'] . ' ' . $row['order_date'] . ' ' . $row['discount'];
            }

    }
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, it is coming in the format 11/12/2014 11/22/2014, where first value is month/ second is date/ last is year

Comment: can you please explain the time() and strtotime() method

Comment: time — Return current Unix timestamp
strtotime — Parse about any English textual datetime description into a Unix timestamp
For more info please check php.net